# Push Item to Array and Delete in the Same Request

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, database

I have a document that stores sensor data where the sensor readings are objects stored in an array. Example:

```
{
  "readings": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1499475320,
      "temperature": 121
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1499475326,
      "temperature": 93
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1499475340,
      "temperature": 142
    }
  ]
}
```

I know how to push/add an item to the "readings" array. But what I need is when I add an item to the array, I also want to "clean" the array by removing items that have "timestamp" value older than a cutoff time.

Is this possible in mongodb?

Comment: @NeilLunn I am trying to get the bulkWrite answer your provided. Once I get it working I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: You have had plenty of time here. This is not an uncommon process and basically on the question you asked the code provided works "as is" with no need for alteration. So there was really nothing for you to do in order to "get it working" than simply implement exactly what is explained. It is not polite to leave answers unaccepted where they do address the question asked, or where you believe it does not to explain why not "in comments on the answer given", so the author is able to reply and address your concerns. Please don't ask questions and then abandon them. People put effort in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see this you basically have two options here that have varying approaches.

### Restrict Arrays to Capped Size

The first option here is "not exactly" what you are asking for, but it is the option with the least implementation and execution overhead. The variance from your question is that instead of "removing past a certain age", we instead simply place a "limit/cap" on the total number of entries in the array.

This is actually done using the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
Model.update(
  { "_id": docId },
  { "$push": { 
    "readings": { 
      "$each": [{ "timestamp": 1499478496679, "temperature": 100 }],
      "$slice": -10
    }
  }
)
```

In this case the `-10` argument restricts the array to only have the "last ten" entries from the end of the array since we are "appending" with [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/push/). If you wanted instead the "latest" as the first entry then you would modify with [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/position/) and instead provide the "positive" value to [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/slice/), which means "first ten" in contrast.

So it's not the same thing you asked for, but it is practical since the arrays do not have "unlimited growth" and you can simply "cap" them as each update is made and the "oldest" item will be removed once at the maximum length. This means the overall document never actually grows beyond a set size, and this is a very good thing for MongoDB.

---

### Issue with Bulk Operations

The next case which actually does exactly what you ask uses "Bulk Operations" to issue "two" update operations in a "single" request to the server. The reason why it is "two" is because there is a rule that you cannot have different update operators "assigned to the same path" in a singe update operation.

Therefore what you want actually involves a [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) AND a [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operation, and on the "same array path" we need to issue those as "separate" operations. This is where the Bulk API can help:

```
Model.collection.bulkWrite([
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": docId },
    "update": {
      "$pull": {
        "readings": { "timestamp": { "$lt": cutOff } }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": docId },
    "update": {
      "$push": { "timestamp": 1499478496679, "temperature": 100 }
    }
  }}
])
```

This uses the [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) method from the underlying driver which you access from the model via `.collection` as shown. This will actually return a [`BulkWriteOpResult`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#~BulkWriteOpResult) within the callback or Promise which contains information about the actual operations performed within the "batch". In this case it will be the "matched" and "modified" numbers which will be appropriate to the operations that were actually performed.

Hence if the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) did not actually "remove" anything since the timestamp values were actually newer than the given constraint, then the modified count would only reflect the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operation. But most of the time this need not concern you, where instead you would just accept that the operations completed without error and did something according to what you actually asked.

---

### Conclude

So the general case of "both" is that it's really all done in one request and one response. The differences come in that "under the hood" the second approach which matches your request actually does do "two" operations per request and therefore takes microseconds longer.

There is actually no reason why you could not "combine" the logic of "both", and remove past your "cutoFF" as well as keeping a "cap" on the overall array size. But the general idea here is that the first implementation, though not exactly the same thing as asked will actually do a "good enough" job of "housekeeping" with little to no additional overhead on the request, or indeed the implementation of the actual code.

Also, whilst you can always "read the data" -> "modify" -> "save". That is not a really great pattern. And for best performance as well as "consistency" without conflict, you should be using the atomic operations to modify in just the same way as is outlined here.